# How do i check if a file exists on remote server using python?

Tags: python

I have some code that copies a file to remote destination. It uses UNC path to map the directory and then perform copy.

The file size is considerable so copying again and again takes time. I need to check if file exists and it is valid as in not corrupted using python. It is an executable file . I am using windows platform.

Comment: & what have you tried so far & failed?

Comment: Why not use [`rsync`](http://rsync.samba.org/)? Its designed exactly for this.

Comment: I have used SFTPclient. But no success with validity of file.

Comment: And moreover i think rsync is for Unix type platforms. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Rsync is cross-platform. https://www.itefix.no/i2/cwrsync

Comment: rsync for windows  [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528298/rsync-for-windows), [two](http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try paramiko sftpclient,

say u have connection

```
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
try:
    sftp.get(remote_path, local_path)
except IOError:
    #set a variable here to know whether file exists
    pass
```